# Handlebars with Express.js - Should I transform raw data in templates or elsewhere?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, templating

I'm going to make a web app using Express, and Handlebars seems to be a good templating engine choice, but I wonder where raw JSON data should be made human-readable: in the templates or in actual JS code?

Let's say I have this piece of JSON:

```
{
  raw_item_name: "Whatever",
  item_quality: 2
}
```

item_quality could represent "Unusual". The human-readable version of this JSON would be "Unusual Whatever", and that's what I want the end user to see on the page. My question is, should I pass this JSON directly to the template and use helpers to transform it, or transform it elsewhere and pass the final string to the template to have it directly display it?

Comment: I would vote for handling it in the templating itself: calling code should not concern itself about how it _thinks_ the template wants to handle it. Maybe you want a color later rather then an "Unusual" text prefix. But it's a judgement call.

Comment: That's my opinion too, I think it's cleaner, but it requires a lot of helpers if I want to do that with Handlebars. I'll see if someone has a Handlebars solution, otherwise I'll use embedded JavaScript.

Comment: See it like this: if you're going to translate your project, ever, keeping the strings separated from templates makes a lot of sense. An i18n helper there, and we've got all the versatility we need to keep templates doing what templates do, helpers for translations, and input is just raw input.